# python3 Function to concat python dictionaries not working

Tags: python, dictionary

I keep getting an empty dictionary

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3


dic1={1:10, 2:20}
dic2={3:30, 4:40}
dic3={5:50,6:60}
dictNew = {}


def concatDict(dictCon):
    dictNew = dict.update(dictCon)
    return dictNew


concatDict(dic1)
concatDict(dic2)
concatDict(dic3)

print(dictNew)
```

dictNew is not getting updated from the function calls.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `dictNew.update(dictCon)`?

Comment: and assign the result of the function...

Comment: Or just  `{**dic1, **dic2, **dic3}`.

Comment: Your function does not modify `dictNew`, it makes a new variable local to `concatDict` called `dictNew`.

Comment: @Denziloe No, it does modify `dictNew` since the `update` method modifies the mutable data type rather than returning a copy as you imply.

Comment: @JoeIddon Run the code if you can't read it. `dictNew` is not modified.

Comment: @Denziloe In this code, yes, but that is because the OP made a mistake - calling `dict.update` rather than `dictNew.update`.

Comment: "In this code, yes"... well obviously? I'm talking about the code they have posted and have asked about.

Comment: @Denziloe My bad, I completely misunderstood your comment!

Comment: @JoeIddon No worries!

Answer (score 1):

For joining dictionaries you can simply use this code:

```
dict1 = {1: 10, 2: 20}
dict2 = {3: 30, 4: 40}
dict3 = {5: 50, 6: 60}
dict_new = {**dic1, **dic2, **dic3}
print(dict_new)
```

Result:

```
{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to update `dictNew` with the `dictCon` dictionary argument. Since dictionaries are mutable, you don't need to save or return the result as `dictNew` will be mutated:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

dic1={1:10, 2:20}
dic2={3:30, 4:40}
dic3={5:50,6:60}
dictNew = {}

def concatDict(dictCon):
    dictNew.update(dictCon)

concatDict(dic1)
concatDict(dic2)
concatDict(dic3)

print(dictNew)
```

which gives:

```
{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60}
```

---

However note that your function is literally just masking `dictNew.update`, so you might as well use that method call instead of this wrapping function:

```
...
dictNew.update(dic1)
dictNew.update(dic2)
dictNew.update(dic3)
...
```

---

A different method is to use the `**`-operator to explode the dicionaries:

```
{**dic1, **dic2, **dic3}
```

Comment: @LevZakharov The function is called `concatDict`, yes `dictNew` could be passed in but if the *purpose of the funciton* is to concat to `dictNew`, then I don't see this is as bad practice. However if this *is* the sole purpose, then why not just use `dictNew.update(...)`! :p

Comment: Global variables are __always__ a bad practice.

Comment: @LevZakharov No, they're not: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/7434365. In  controlled cases where the operation is simple and known, they are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Here is no reason to use global variables. If you can not use them - do not use them.

Comment: I am trying to practice functions and dictionaries at the same time. This change  def concatDict(dictCon):
    dictNew.update(dictCon)  did excatly what I was hoping for.

Comment: @LevZakharov Each to themselves, but personally I consider this a simple enough application that demonstrates the concept of mutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `concatDicts` function to accept a variable number of dict as input and return a new merged dict

```
>>> dic1 = {1:10, 2:20}
>>> dic2 = {3:30, 4:40}
>>> dic3 = {5:50, 6:60}
>>>
>>> def concatDicts(*dicts):
...     return dict((k,v) for dic in dicts for k,v in dic.items())
... 
>>>
>>> new_dic = concatDicts(dic1, dic2, dic3)
>>> print(new_dic)
{1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60}
```